# glitchy, pixilated text and menus

Tags: system-installation, graphics, ubuntu-studio, additional-drivers

New Ubuntu Studio install on MSI motherboard using AMD Ryzen 5 with vega graphics on the CPU.  I'm assuming this needs some kind of driver.  I'm brand new to linux so please be detailed with your response.  Thanks for the help.

[image: glitchy graphics]

Comment: You shouldn't need any more drivers, but this does look like some kind of graphics incompatibility. While not Ubuntu, this might give you a hint or two: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AMDGPU. While Linux does try to be compatible with everything, it isn't guaranteed to work on all hardware, so keep that in mind.

Comment: Additionally, there is a low-level noise-kind of a grainy, digital noise, I can hear though my speakers which seems to correspond with the pixilation of menus and any kind of moving text.  Again, I'm a new user, so trying to find answers has been frustrating since I don't understand all of the terminology  Thanks.